# Excel VBA .SaveAs breaking in loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel workbook broken out with multiple worksheets, 1 per customer. In my code, I am trying to save each individual customer worksheet as its own excel file. However, the .SaveAs command breaks the second time it triggers in the loop. Any pointers would be fantastic.

```
Dim SchedWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim SchedWorkbook As Workbook
Dim SchedName As String

Set SchedWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set SchedWorksheet = ActiveSheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each Worksheet In SchedWorkbook.Sheets
    If Worksheet.Name = "Instructions" Or Worksheet.Name = "Invoice_Items" 
    Or Worksheet.Name = "Customers" Or _
       Worksheet.Name = "Terms" Or Worksheet.Name = "Dilution_Type" Or 
       Worksheet.Name = "Approval_Status" Or _
       Worksheet.Name = "Carriers" Then
        GoTo NextSched
    End If

    If Worksheet.Name = "Invoices" Then
        'basicScheduleFileName is global set at beginning of program
        SchedName = basicScheduleFileName & "ALL"
    Else
        SchedName = Worksheet.Name
    End If

    'payoutFileName is global set at beginning of program
    Worksheet.SaveAs Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & payoutFileName 
    & "\Basic Schedule" & "\" & SchedName, xlOpenXMLWorkbook

NextSched:
Next Worksheet
```

The error on the second iteration is as follows: 
Run-time error 1004 'Application-defined or object-defined error'

I have also attempted to run this loop using the SchedWorksheet object in lieu of Worksheet and get the error "method .SaveAs of object _Worksheet failed" on the second iteration.

**Question** I have code extremely similar to his code earlier in my program that takes a similar dataset and uses an exportAsFixedFormat call to save each worksheet as a PDF. Is there an equivalent for .xlsx? (.csv would be fine as well)

Comment: "...breaks the second time..."  - Do you get an error? What error?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not including that in the OP:  "Run-time error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: Where/how do you declare and define `payoutFileName`. Also, what's `SchedName` the first time it's run, and the second?

Comment: Also what is `basicScheduleFileName` ?

Comment: try adding ".xlsx" to the end of your SchedName

Comment: also Worksheet.activate is not a valid variable name

Comment: It is best to [edit] your question to include all the pertinent information rather than just adding comments.

Comment: Thank you for all of the replies. In order:  
**payoutFileName** is a global set at the beginning of the program and never changed. 

**SchedName first time** - Basic_Schedule-ALL  **SchedName second time** - Basic_Schedule-Blackduck (both valid and expected). 

**basicScheduleFileName** is another global like payoutFileName that is set at the beginning of the program and never changed. 

Tried .xlsx, no change. 

Removed Worksheet.Activate, essentially that is there because I was just throwing things at the wall.

Comment: Does the first iteration skip the save as portion?

Comment: @NickSlash No, the first save as fires and saves the file as expected, it's the next one that breaks. I assume it is maybe losing focus or a reference or something, but I am not sure.

Comment: Cant replicate your issue, with your current code you appear to be saving a copy of the entire workbook and not the specific sheet. Although this might just be something I did...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what value "payOutFileName" has so I left it out of the code.  I also don't know the value for basicScheduleFileName so I set it to "Something."  You will have to change that to whatever you need to change it too.  This works fine when saving to my dir "C\Files"  Might be a little buggy for you.  Hopefully it will be a start.

```
Sub asdfghj()
Dim SchedWorkbook As Workbook
Dim SchedName As String
Dim basicScheduleFileName As String
Dim payoutFileName As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

basicScheduleFileName = "Something"
Set SchedWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each ws In SchedWorkbook.Sheets
Debug.Print ws.Name
    If ws.Name = "Instructions" Or ws.Name = "Invoice_Items" _
    Or ws.Name = "Customers" Or _
       ws.Name = "Terms" Or ws.Name = "Dilution_Type" Or _
       ws.Name = "Approval_Status" Or _
       ws.Name = "Carriers" Then
        GoTo NextSched
    End If

    If ws.Name = "Invoices" Then
        SchedName = basicScheduleFileName & "ALL" & ".xlsx"
    Else
        SchedName = ws.Name & ".xlsx"
    End If

    ws.Activate

'    SaveAs Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & payoutFileName & "\Basic Schedule" & "\" & SchedName, xlOpenXMLWorkbook

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    ws.Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
    wb.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Files\" & SchedName, FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    wb.Close

NextSched:
Next ws



End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to get this put together. Unfortunately, as with all of my other attempts, this code works the first iteration of the loop and then breaks on the next.

Comment: Do you know how to set a break point to debug?  We need to find the exact line where it stops at.  Since it works fine on my Excel 2013 I am not able to detect your bad line.  You'll have to do this yourself.  Check out this site on debugging.  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

Comment: The code breaks on the .SaveAs line, which is the same behavior I saw in my earlier code.  Let me ask you a question about your code, I have at least a dozen or so worksheets that I need to save as separate files in my code. The code you provided closes the workbook (`wb.Close`)after the first save, won't that kick me out of the loop once I have saved once?

Comment: `wb` is a new workbook, not the one executing the code so there is no issue closing it.

Comment: Nick is correct.  The new workbook you created is set to wb, so when yu close wb you are closing the new workbook.  But at least now we know where your code is throwing an error.  And you say it is on the second time you try to save a worksheet, not the first time.  so put  abreak point on the saveas line.  When it stops the first time hit PF5 to let it finish the the first worksheet.  When it comes back the second time, and stops you can hover your mouse over the variables of the path and file name to see their values. they are probably incompatible filename or the path is non-existent.

Comment: @JohnMuggins I just reviewed your code again and my "fix" and realize we came to the same answer. Sincere apologies, I must have done something incorrect in my code when I ported your answer over. I blame how frazzled I was yesterday. I thought I was having an epiphany today, perhaps my brain just finally caught up to what you were telling me all along.

Answer (score 1):

First off, thanks to everyone who took time and brainpower trying to figure out my issue. I finally figured out a fix that works.
**First** I made sure to get rid of ActiveWorkbook and ActiveSheet references to avoid any confusion in Excel.
**Second** As @NickSlash pointed out, it was likely that even if my code did work, it would save multiple copies of the same file under different names. So, to solve that while fixing my original issue, I changed my code to copy the worksheets that I need into a new workbook and save them that way:

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim NWB As Workbook
Dim SchedName As String

Set WB = Workbooks("Basic_Schedule-.xls")
WB.Activate

'Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each WS In WB.Sheets
    WB.Activate

    If WS.Name = "Instructions" Or WS.Name = "Invoice_Items" Or WS.Name = "Customers" Or _
       WS.Name = "Terms" Or WS.Name = "Dilution_Type" Or WS.Name = "Approval_Status" Or _
       WS.Name = "Carriers" Then
        GoTo NextSched
    End If

    If WS.Name = "Invoices" Then
        SchedName = basicScheduleFileName & "ALL" & ".xlsx"
    Else
        SchedName = WS.Name & ".xlsx"
    End If


    'Copy sheet to another WB
    Set NWB = Workbooks.Add
    WB.Activate
    Sheets(WS.Name).Copy After:=NWB.Sheets(NWB.Sheets.Count)
    NWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
    NWB.SaveAs filename:=basicScheduleFilePath & "\" & payoutFileName & "\Basic Schedule" & "\" & SchedName
    NWB.Close
    WB.Activate

NextSched:
Next WS
```

Instead of this:

```
'Copy sheet to another WB
Set NWB = Workbooks.Add
WB.Activate
Sheets(WS.Name).Copy After:=NWB.Sheets(NWB.Sheets.Count)
NWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
NWB.SaveAs filename:=basicScheduleFilePath & "\" & payoutFileName & "\Basic Schedule" & "\" & SchedName
NWB.Close
WB.Activate
```

Do this -- you can avoid the "Activate" method call, and also if you have a reference to `WS` as an object, it's redundant to do `WB.Sheets(WS.Name)` when `WS` already refers to the same Worksheet.

```
'Copy sheet to another WB
WS.Copy '## Creates a new workbook with the copied sheet.
Set NWB = ActiveWorkbook
NWB.SaveAs filename:=basicScheduleFilePath & "\" & payoutFileName & "\Basic Schedule" & "\" & SchedName
NWB.Close
```

Comment: Made a suggestion to improve your solution, edited it in to your answer above. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you very much for the additional tips @DavidZemens I will make those changes.